# Pip fails to install aldryn country segment requirements

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, django-cms

I have installed *aldryn-segmentation* using pip and am trying to install *aldryn-country-segment* using `pip install https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-country-segment/archive/master.zip` as the documentation suggests.
However I get an error that it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement *aldryn-geoip*.

```
Collecting aldryn-geoip (from aldryn-country-segment==0.7.2)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aldryn-geoip (from aldryn-country-segment==0.7.2) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for aldryn-geoip (from aldryn-country-segment==0.7.2)
```

or when downloading file and running `python setup.py install` it gives me this: (after lots of other text)

```
Processing dependencies for aldryn-country-segment==0.7.2
Searching for aldryn-geoip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/aldryn-geoip/
Couldn't find index page for 'aldryn-geoip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for aldryn-geoip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('aldryn-geoip')
```

Is there an obvious workaround to this?

Comment: Please add all relevant parts of the output!

Comment: at https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-country-segment there is: `NOTICE

This app will not work on Aldryn until Aldryn includes the MaxMind GeoIP C-API into their build pack.` so I'm not sure there is a workaround _yet_.

Comment: The output has been added. 
I saw that but I figured it would have meant that you can't use it on the Aldryn service but still use it in your own project. As I understand it Aldryn host DjangoCMS projects but this is not what I am using it for.

Comment: Try to install from the *.tar.gz file. Not the pip way.

Comment: @PouyaAbbassi where do I find the *.tar.gz for this package? It hasn't been added to pip yet so I've been pip installing directly from github.

Comment: I found this link:  [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) relating to GeoIP. How ever it doesn't solve the aldryn-geoip issue.

Comment: Hello there, I'm one of the maintainers for aldryn-geoip. Currently aldryn-geoip is a private repo (and thus released privately). This is quite unfortunate but it's because of the licensing of the maxmind data. We're currently working on how to provide the app with an easy to use interface on Aldryn without packaging the data.

Comment: @Paulo thankyou for your reply. I have implemented my own workaround, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Download and save the file somewhere in your system.
Then unzip it and cd to the directory. You'll get something like this:

```
.
├── addon.json                                                                                                                                                                   
├── aldryn_config.py                                                                                                                                                             
├── country_segment                                                                                                                                                              
│   ├── cms_plugins.py                                                                                                                                                           
│   ├── __init__.py                                                                       │   ├── locale
│   │   └── fr
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           ├── django.mo
│   │           └── django.po
│   ├── middleware
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── resolve_country_code_middleware.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── south_migrations
│       ├── 0001_initial.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── schemamigration.py
└── setup.py

7 directories, 17 files
```

Then run `sudo python setup.py install` and python will install the package to your system.
You may need to install `aldryn-geoip` as dependency too. (using the same way)

Comment: Thanks but the issue is I can't find `aldryn-geoip` to install it.

Comment: Still can't find it. Looked all over GitHub as well

Comment: same issue here with aldryn-geoip

Comment: aldryn-geoip is found here https://devpi.divio.ch/aldryn/patches/+f/24b/efbdca1a3ef64/aldryn-geoip-1.0.0.dev1.tar.gz